# recover partitions hive in HDinsight

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to recover partitions from blob in hdinsight. I am using below queries,

```
'ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS;'

'MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;'
```

None of these queries work to recover the partitions. can you anyone suggest how to recover partitions in hdinsight using hive. thanks

Comment: Try : Refresh table tablename